# What "this" means when we mention it after return type

Tags: c#

I came across following code ,
I an unable to understand what "this" means in the following code.

```
public Return-Type this[string param1, int param2]
{

}
```

Comment: It means [`Indexers` (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x16t2tx.aspx). Next time, please use Google first..

Comment: I believe there is lot of duplicated questions here..

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy Because using Google is too mainstream `:)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's called `indexer`. You can read the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x16t2tx.aspx)

> Indexers allow instances of a class or struct to be indexed just like arrays. Indexers resemble properties except that their accessors take parameters.

Usually all arrays and collections has at least one `indexer`.For example here is the implementation of `List<T>` indexer:

```
public T this[int index] {
   get {
            if ((uint) index >= (uint)_size) {
                ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentOutOfRangeException();
            }

            Contract.EndContractBlock();
            return _items[index]; 
        }
```

`List<T>` has an internal `Array` of type `T` and it's indexer returning the item of that array at the specific index.